# SQL query to check if the next row value is same or different

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am joining two tables based on a common column `date`. However, the column I am trying to get from one the table (`cmg`) in this case, should get next row value only if it is different from its previous row's value

**Table A**

```
Date            comp.no
-----------------------
2019-03-08        5
2019-02-26        5
2019-01-17        5
2019-01-10        5
2018-12-27        5
```

**Table B**

```
    Date         cmg
    -----------------
2019-07-17  NULL

2019-04-20  NULL
2019-02-26  RHB
2019-01-19  NULL
2019-01-17  RHB
2019-01-10  RMB
2018-12-28  NULL
2018-12-27  RHB
2018-12-12  RUB
2018-11-28  RUB
2018-10-20  NULL
2018-07-21  NULL
2018-04-21  NULL
2018-01-20  NULL
2017-10-21  NULL
2017-07-29  NULL
2017-05-07  NULL
2017-02-13  NULL
2016-11-22  NULL
2016-08-29  NULL
2016-06-07  NULL
2016-04-06  RUB
2016-03-21  RUB
2016-03-07  RUB
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? This looks like a gaps and islands question.

Comment: Have u looked for `distinct` and `max`  in internet, lots of resources available, we would like to know any attempt you have made so far

Comment: I tried using lag and lead function, but couldn't get expected output

Comment: Could you describe the logic more, or give a more complex example with the data. From the data you've provided it looks like a simple `MAX(Date)` `GROUP BY cmg`, but sounds like what you actually need is a bit more complex?

Comment: @ChrisMack,
I have updated the dataset

Comment: Having said, u tried with `lead` and `lag`, can you please post us your query, also expected result based on above tables please

Answer (score 0):

You can use lag function to compare with previous value. And for the first row you'll need an isnull() check since the first row won't have a previous value.

```
;with cte as(
select case 
when  isnull(lag(t2.cmg)over (order by t2.cmg desc),'') <>t2.cmg then 1 else 0 end as isresult
,t2.date,t2.cmg
 from TableA t1
inner join TableB t2
on  t1.date=t2.date
)
select date,cmg from cte where isresult=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()`:

```
select date, cmg
from (select b.date, b.cmg, lag(b.cmg) over (order by b.date) as prev_cmg
      from a join
           b
           on a.date = b.date
     ) b
where prev_cmg is null or prev_cmg <> cmg
order by date;
```